# Iterate over object with private attributes

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm using PHP with php active record.  When i retrieve a record from the database the attributes are listed as private.  I need to iterate over the attributes and retrieve the key => value pair.  How can this be done?

```
$row = \Models\Locations::find(2);

Models\Locations Object
(
    [errors] => 
    [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [customer_id] => 6
            [name] => test location
            [address_line1] => 123 test Drive
            [address_line2] => 
            [city] => Moon Township
            [state] => AZ
            [zip] => 12345
            [country] => USA
            [primary_phone_number] => 123.456.7890
            [latitude] => 0
            [longitude] => 0
            [coordinate_precision] => 
        )

    [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
    [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the model's method [attributes](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#methodattributes):
`$row->attributes()`

Comment: Just as a quick test i tried $row->attributes() and it worked!  I can now iterate over the return.  Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop over everything then youll need to implment the [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface.

```
class ModelExtended extends Model implements Iterator
{
   // implement the Iterator interface within - then extend this class instead of Model 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not, unless you have a public accessible getter function that allows you to get the array.

Comment: The [`ActiveRecord\Model` implements `__get` and `__set`](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Model.php) to access the attributes - so he does have public accessors - the part hes missing is the implementation of a `Traversable` interface of some sort.